# thrust::sort_by_key is much slower than qsort

Tags: sorting, cuda, qsort

i found thrust::sort_by_key is much slower than qsort , it comfused me that parallel sorting have low performance, why?

The dataset is 100.
The qsort time is 0.000026(s).
The GPU_sort time is 0.000912(s).

The dataset is 1000.
The qsort time is 0.000205. 
The GPU_sort time is 0.003177.

The dataset is 10000.
The qsort time is 0.001598.
The GPU_sort time is 0.031547.

The dataset is 100000.
The qsort time is 0.018564.
The GPU_sort time is 0.31230.

The dataset is 1000000.
The qsort time is 0.219892.
The GPU_sort time is 3.138608.

The dataset is 10000000.
The qsort time is 2.581469.
The GPU_sort time is 85.456543.

here is my codes:

```
struct HashValue{
int id_;
float proj_;
 };

int HashValueQsortComp(const void* e1, const void* e2)                      

{

int ret = 0;

HashValue* value1 = (HashValue *) e1;

HashValue* value2 = (HashValue *) e2;

if (value1->proj_ < value2->proj_) {
    ret = -1;
} else if (value1->proj_ > value2->proj_) {
    ret = 1;
} else {
    if (value1->id_ < value2->id_) ret = -1;
    else if (value1->id_ > value2->id_) ret = 1;
}
return ret;
}


const int N = 10;

void sort_test()
{

clock_t start_time = (clock_t)-1.0;
clock_t end_Time = (clock_t)-1.0;

HashValue *hashValue = new HashValue[N];
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    hashValue[i].id_ = i;
    hashValue[i].proj_ = rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/1000);
}

start_time = clock();
qsort(hashValue, N, sizeof(HashValue), HashValueQsortComp);
end_Time = clock();
printf("The qsort time is %.6f\n", ((float)end_Time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

float *keys = new float[N];
int *values = new int[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    keys[i] = hashValue[i].proj_;
    values[i] = hashValue[i].id_;
}
start_time = clock();
thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys+N, values);
end_Time = clock();
printf("The GPU_sort time is %.6f\n", ((float)end_Time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

delete[] hashValue;
hashValue = NULL;

delete[] keys;
keys = NULL;

delete[] values;
values = NULL;
}
```

Comment: The device is K40.    And my cpu is 1200.468 MHz, GenuineIntel

Comment: you do understand that the thrust sort isn't running on the gpu?

Answer (score 1):

The variables (`keys`, `values`)  you are passing to thrust sort:

```
thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys+N, values);
```

are **host** variables.  That means [thrust will dispatch the host path](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) for the algorithm, which does not run on the GPU.  Refer to the [thrust quickstart guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) to learn more about thrust, and [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) is a worked example of using thrust with device variables.

Apparently, the host-dispatched thrust sort is slower than your `qsort` implementation.  It may be faster if you use the device path (and time the thrust sort operation only).